# Authenticate a user using a nodejs web server but no framework

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, authentication, restful-authentication

still trying to learn javascript and nodejs. I got to a point where i have a server in node, it routes my requests, answers me, queries the mysql db and i think works quite well!, problem is, im going to need some way to authenticate a user that will be the only one able to edit, delete or create records in the db.

It would be something like this:
User1 - browses the page, all select queries, except some that will increment a visits counter
User2 - the admin, all powerful

I have investigated and found several ways of doing this, i don't understand them very well, but they all seem to require me to rewrite almost all my server! I used what i think is pure nodejs for it,

```
var http = require("http"); 
var url = require("url");
```

I also used sequelize to connect to my db.

Investigating i found this:
- http://passportjs.org/
The problem with passport is that it works with express, and i would have to rewrite all

- expressjs
  Again, rewrite
- http://mcavage.me/node-restify/
  And i also found restify, which looks awesome, but it would mean a complete rewrite of something that already works.
- nodejs
  i cant seem to find something about authentication in the nodejs docs.

I have never done authentication and i cant understand how they work without involving the db, what i understand as authentication is: a user logs in, and his requests connect to the database using a db user with certain access, i know how to do the db side, but what happens between the client and the server until it reaches the db is beyond me.

I will post all the sources, feel free to skip them, hopefully, they will help someone looking to do the same thing.

basically, the only things left i think are some kind of authentication and the ability to upload an image from the browser to the server, and save it in the server.
I will implement an angularjs client (which im still yet to learn) that will make all the requests.

Any help will be really appreciated!

index.js

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");

var handle = {};
handle["/insertHood"] = requestHandlers.insertHood;
handle["/selectHood"] = requestHandlers.selectHood;


server.start(router.route, handle);
```

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url"); //This module has utilities for URL resolution and parsing.  http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_url

function start(route, handle) {
    //the web service will respond with this
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var urlValues = {
            params: {},
            pathName: ""
        };
        var postData = "";

        //read the url used to call our web service
        parseUrl(request, urlValues);
        //console.log("path: " + urlValues.pathName);
        //console.log("params: " + JSON.stringify(urlValues.params));

        //set encoding for the recieved request
        request.setEncoding("utf8");

        //if post data is recieved process it here by chunks
        request.addListener("data", function (postDataChunk) {
            postData += postDataChunk;
            console.log("Recieved POST data chunk '" + postDataChunk + "'.");
        }
        );

        //when we are done storing all the post data, go to the pathName
        request.addListener("end", function () {
            route(handle, urlValues, response, postData);
        }
        );
    }
    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started");
}

function parseUrl(request, urlValues) {
    urlValues.pathName = url.parse(request.url).pathname; //parse the url pathName
    urlValues.params = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
}

exports.start = start;
exports.parseUrl = parseUrl;
```

router.js

```
function route(handle, urlValues, response, postData) {
    console.log("Router.js --> About to route a request for " + urlValues.pathName);
    if (typeof handle[urlValues.pathName] === 'function') {
        handle[urlValues.pathName](response, urlValues, postData);
    } else {
        response.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
        response.write("404, no request handler found for " + urlValues.pathName);
        response.end();
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

requesthandlers.js

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
var db = require("./dataBase");

function insertHood(response, urlValues) {
    urlValues.params["zoom_level"] = parseInt(urlValues.params["zoom_level"]);
    urlValues.params["lat"] = parseFloat(urlValues.params["lat"], 10);
    urlValues.params["lon"] = parseFloat(urlValues.params["lon"], 10);

    console.log("requestHandler.js --> Request handler 'insertHood' was called.");
    var result = db.execute("modify", 'INSERT INTO neighborhood (hood_location, hood_name, zoom_level) values (GeomFromText(\'POINT(:lat :lon)\'), :name, :zoom_level)', response, urlValues.params);
}

function selectHood(response, urlValues) {
    console.log("requestHandler.js --> Request handler 'selectHood' was called.");
    var result = db.execute("select", 'select x(hood_location), y(hood_location), hood_name, zoom_level from neighborhood where hood_name = :name', response, urlValues.params);
}

exports.insertHood = insertHood;
exports.selectHood = selectHood;
```

database.js

```
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");

//this tells sequelize how to connect to the data base
//see http://sequelizejs.com/documentation#usage-basics
var sequelize = new Sequelize('mydb', 'myuser', 'mypass',
    {
        host: "localhost",
        port: 3306,
        dialect: 'mysql'
    }
);

/*
Pre:
type: a string to know if the query is a select and returns rows, or a modify query, and returns nothing
query: an sql query in string format with the parameters :param in place
response: a response object where the results of the query will be written
parameters: from sequelize, an array with the parameter for the sql query in the correct order

Pos:
response: the object will have the results of the query, an error or the rows of the results set
*/
function execute(type, query, response, parameters) {
    console.log("Query: " + query); 
    var options = { raw: true };

    var result = sequelize.query(query, null, options, parameters)
    .success(function (rows) {        
        if (type == 'select') {
            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "application/json" });
            response.write(JSON.stringify(rows));
            response.end();
        } else if (type == 'modify') {
            response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
            response.write("Query was successful");
            response.end();
        }
    }
    ).error(function (e) {
        console.log("An error occured: ", e);
        response.writeHead(404, { "Content-Type": "text/html" });
        response.write("There was an error man, shits on fire yo ---> " + e);
        response.end();
    }
    );
}

exports.execute = execute;
```

Answer (score 4):

Basic authentication is not too difficult, even without an external framework. The most difficult part is really just properly maintaining sessions. I would *strongly* recommend that you use [session](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-session.html) for this, but it is not a necessity. Connect's session is really ideal here, because it manages expired sessions so that you don't have an ever-increasing object.

In order to maintain authentication, once a user has input their credentials and they are sent to the server, crosscheck them with the valid credentials; If they match, then  you will need to store a cookie on the client-side with a unique UUID. On the server side, keep an object containing hashes of all authenticated users. This way, as soon as a user connects, the server can check if they already have a cookie proving their credentials, so that you don't have to log in on every page.

Something like this should work in basic cases:

Routing:

`var sessions = {}`

```
if(req.headers.cookies['sid'] && sessions[req.headers.cookies['sid']])
    //continue
else
    //return login page
```

On user login:

```
if(req.query.username == someUsername && req.query.password == somePassword){
      res.writeHead(200, {
          'Set-Cookie': 'sid=UUID', //will need a uuidgen here
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
      })
      sessions[UUID] = true //store session on server
      return res.send(200,somePage)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, what you said gave me some ideas, but is still dont get some things, this is what i was gonna do: once the user logs in, store his credentials in a cookie. when he makes a request, send via POST his credentials and use them to authenticate on the data base. if the cookie doesnt have credentials then he is not logged and i should ask him to. i would connect and disconnect from the db each time a request is made, is this ok? Also, how do you know in your example whose credential to check for in the hash? how do you manage the db connections?

Comment: @Toddy It is generally insecure to store user credentials client side, and there is no reason you should need to do so. The point of the hash is that it is a unique identifier for that particular user's validation status on the server. Connecting to the database on every request is both time-consuming and unnecessary.You should just be keeping the db connection open on the server, and decide whether or not to allow a read/writes based on whether the user is validated.